# How to display all columns/fields in all user tables?

Tags: sql, system, sybase

Running sybase. Trying to see all columns for all my tables with type, length, column name and table name. This is what im trying to run:

```
select tbl.name as tablename, col.name as columnname, typ.name as columntype, col.length as size 
from syscolumns col, sysobjects tbl, systypes typ
where col.id = tbl.id
and col.type = typ.type
and tbl.type='U'
```

I've noticed in the systypes table that theres more than one type for each type ID (e.g. type id #39 has over 50 entries but varchar is the one I want). Not only are the types returned wrong, i'm getting way more rows when executed than columns that exist in my tables.

Comment: Im an idiot :D

it should be col.usertype = typ.usertype.

Comment: I would recommend you use JOIN for tables instead of WHERE clauses

Answer (score 0):

minor change in your query

> select tbl.name as tablename, col.name as columnname, typ.name as
>   columntype, col.length as size  from syscolumns col, sysobjects tbl,
>   systypes typ where col.id = tbl.id and col.usertype = typ.usertype and
>   tbl.type='U'